# Strange Kotlin school project

Tags: kotlin

We're starting to dig into Kotlin at school and we've just started learning about looping, for statements and if/else statements. We used these so far to create a little program that takes a number input from the user and turns it into a "box" made out of asterisk symbols, but with spaces in the middle. That works all fine and well, but now the teacher wants us to use the same methods to create a half triangle, but with it being hollow in the middle just like the box we made before. I'm having a tough time figuring out where to combine what we've learned. I think I'm close, but I can't quite figure out where I'm going wrong.

What I have so far is:

```
 fun main() {
        println("Please enter size of line: ")
    var size = readLine()!!.toInt()

    for (i in 1..size) {
        print("*")
        for (i in 1..(size-1)) {
            print(" ")

        }
        println("*")
        size++
    }


    for( i in 1..size) {
        print("*")
    }
}
```

Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated, final product should look something like this (assuming your input was '8')

```
*
**
* *
*  *
*   *
*    *
*     *
********
```

Comment: What does the output look like? How does it differ from what you expected?

Comment: Hints/suggestions: 1. Do you need two asterisks on the first line? 2. Handwrite out some example triangles and look at each line individually. Find the common pattern between lines 3. Instead of print() and println() you could construct each line as a string and then call println() once in the outer loop.

Comment: Updated it, I had left out what it should look like. My apologies!

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to complete your assignment so here's a hint. I think the part you are missing is thinking about the relation of the inner loop to the outer loop.

```
fun main() {
    println("Please enter size of line: ")
    var size = readLine()!!.toInt()

    for (i in 1..size) {
        print("*")
        for (j in 1..??) { // TODO - think about the relation of j to current i
            print(" ")

        }
        println("*")
       // size++ - this is adding an extra increment you don't need
    }

   for( i in 1..size) {
       print("*")
   } 
}
```